# Profile field pre and field post help on search pages

Tags: profile, search

I am finding that field pre and post help do not display in Edit Search Query forms.  Nor does form help, or even formatting fields.  Am I missing something?

We have a membership directory that our members (public, not logged in) can use to lookup information on other members.  It works.

However it's not obvious to them that they can use mysql wildcards to search for words within strings of text.  For example use "%biology% to search the "Interests" custom field, which contains a free form description of what interests the member.